# Polymerのtemplate作成の際にimportするPolymer Elementについて

Tags: html5, polymer, web-component

お世話になっております。

現在Polymer1.3を使用し、Web開発をしております。
そこで質問ですが、

独自Elementを定義する際にimportする

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
```

等はメインページのhtml(index.html等)のhead内で読み込ませるのか
それとも独自Elementファイル内で読み込ませるべきなのか悩んでおります。
もちろん複数の独自Elementが使用しているコンポーネントのみですが。。

現在メインページのhtmlのhead内で共通するElementは全て読み込ませてるのですが、ページのロードが遅くなった気がしてます。他に原因があるのかもしれませんが、変更してからAw snap!等のエラーページが出るようになったように思います。

それぞれの独自Element内で読み込ませてもいいと思うのですが、

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

などは全Element共通ですのでメインで読ませてもいいのかなと思っています。
また、paper-inputなどを複数の独自Elementが利用しているのでこれもメインでいいとは思うのですが、
みなさまどのような実装をされているのでしょうか？

アドバイスを頂きたく投稿いたしました。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

個人的には、ファイル毎に利用しているコンポーネントをそれぞれ import するのが鉄則であると思います。

HTML Imports はグローバルな定義を増やすので、どこで import しても結果は変わらないのですが、私は、グローバルな定義に依存するとソフトウェアの見通しが悪くなると考えています。そのため、なるべく利用場所の近くに import 文を書くのが良いと思います。JavaScript の Modules がローカル変数にインポートしたモノを割りつけるのも、同じ考えからでしょう。